# Insert list of tuples into sqlite3 database with unknown tuple size

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-insert

I am currently inserting a list of tuples into a and sql table with 4 variables as follows:

```
conn.executemany('INSERT INTO table values (?,?,?,?)', values_list)
```

However, I want to make this more flexible by allowing the tuples parsed to be any length, i.e. any number of variables. Is there a way to do something like the following ?

```
conn.executemany(f'INSERT INTO table values {(?)*len(values_list[0])}', values_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

If a table has 3 columns like `col1`, `col2`, `col3` then you can insert new rows like this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename(col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

or without enumerating all the column names:

```
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

or if you don't want to pass a value for one of the columns, say `col2`:

```
INSERT INTO tablename(col1, col3) VALUES (?, ?)
```

The above statements work because each of the `?` values will be passed to its respective column.

But a statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (?, ?)
```

would fail with the error:

> table tablename has 3 columns but 2 values were supplied

So unless you supply the column names that will receive the passed values you can't pass fewer values to the `INSERT` statement.